Error referencing static files with Vue (CLI) in Electron.js
I'm starting to study Electron and lately I've been having problems with static file references after building an application. I've tried a lot of things and none of them have worked.
My project structure is similar to:
/my-project
  /public
  /src
    /components
    /assets
      /img
        image.png
    /views
    /App.vue
    /main.js
  /electron.js
  /vue.config.js

When I start the application I get the message: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Source of the running application
In the same way I get other errors when trying to access other routes in the application, like this one
My build (config) is configured like this:
"build": {
        "appId": "com.gerenciapet.app",
        "productName": "GerenciaPet",
        "directories": {
            "output": "build_electron"
        },
        "files": [
            "dist/**/*",
            "main.js",
            "preload.js",
            "database.db",
            "!dist/**/*.map"
        ],
        "extraResources": [
            "src/assets/**/*"
        ],
        "win": {
            "icon": "public/favicon.ico",
            "target": "nsis"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "oneClick": false,
            "perMachine": true,
            "allowElevation": true,
            "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
            "createDesktopShortcut": true,
            "createStartMenuShortcut": true
        }
    }

My vue.config.json looks like this:
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "./" : "/",
    assetsDir: "assets",
    outputDir: "dist",
    filenameHashing: false,
    transpileDependencies: true,
});

My electron.js file is loading the index file like this:
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));

And I'm importing the image to use like this:
import mainImage from '@/assets/img/cat-astronaut-amico.png';

I've tried literally everything, I've changed all the paths, I've tried modifying the vue and electron paths, changing the folder names, clearing the cache, removing/adding asar, among others.

I'm struggling to reproduce this issue when using the same electron-builder and Vue config. Seems like some assets are not getting bundled correctly during the Vue production build. But when I import e.g. @/assets/img/whatever.png it ends up in dist/img (or gets inlined as a data URL) where Electron picks it up as expected. If this is just a study project, consider publishing the sources to help others reproduce the issue.

@mwopitz You can find the project source code here: https://github.com/henrilima/gerenciapet. Feel free to check it out and let me know if you find anything. Thank you in advance.
